# How could I modify a Turing machine that attempts to move the head past the leftmost square(crash) on some inputs so that it doesn't crash at all?

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity, turing-machines

Suppose that M is a TM that crashes on some inputs. How would I modify M so that the new machine accepts the same language but does not crash on any input ?

Comment: What does "crash" mean? If you mean "there is no valid transition" then just add a transition for those situations so the TM loops forever or something.

Comment: @jozefg A Turing Machine crashes when it attempts to move the head past the leftmost square

Comment: What's the purpose of doing this? No particular mathematical significance is attached to a TM "crashing" on an input, as opposed to e.g. looping forever. In both cases TM doesn't halt on that input, doesn't accept the string or doesn't have an output.

Comment: @BrianO I know. I just want the machine not to crash. It doesn't matter if it runs forever on some inputs or reject. The point is that I don't want it to crash at any input.

Comment: If you don't care about an O(n) startup cost, why not just move the input string once cell the the right, come back and put a new symbol @ in the first cell, move one cell right, run the TM. The TM adds  transitions for every original state $q$; on scanning @, halt but don't accept & don't crash.